# How to insert multiple values by index into list at one time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there was a way to insert multiple variables into a list at one time using the same index. So for example, let's say we have a list of

`[a, b, c]`

and

`[0,1,2,3,4]`

and I wanted to insert the first list such that the end result is,

`[a, 0, 1, b, 2, 3, c, 4]`

But if I was going to do it individually using `list.insert(pos, value)`and used the positions of `[0, 2, 4]` then the subsequent positions used becomes invalid since it was relating to the old list of 5 elements instead of 6 now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list_a = [0,1,2,3,4]
list_b = ["a", "b", "c"]
pos    = [0, 2, 4]

assert(len(list_b) == len(pos))
acc = 0
for i in range(len(list_b)):
    list_a.insert(pos[i]+acc, list_b[i])
    acc += 1

print(list_a)
```

> ['a', 0, 1, 'b', 2, 3, 'c', 4]

Comment: This works perfectly. Just like to remind others that it only works if the positions and their respective elements are ordered correctly so if you had positions [3, 0, 2, 4] for example, it won't work.

Comment: @Loc-Tran an `assert` statement added.

Comment: The order of inserts should not matter. Your solution does not work for `list_b = ["b", "a", "c"]` and `pos = [2, 0, 4]`. It should give the same result but it does not.

Answer (score 7):

One simple option is to add the items starting with the position with highest value, and then continue with the 2nd highest value, etc.

This way you can using the original method, without any problem of "old/new position"

Comment: Simple, I like it. I was about to create a whole index of positions, but this is far the best solution here.

Answer (score 3):

One ways without using a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ind = [0, 2, 4]
>>> d = dict(zip(ind, b))

>>> [t for k in [(d.get(i),j) for i,j in enumerate(a)] for t in k if t is not None]
['a', 0, 1, 'b', 2, 3, 'c', 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, doesn't use an index accumulator but still requires the indices to be in ascending order.

```py
newObjects = ["a", "b", "c"]
newObjectIndices = [0, 2, 4]
existingList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for index, obj in zip(reversed(newObjectIndices), reversed(newObjects)):
    existingList.insert(index, obj)

print(existingList)       # ['a', 0, 1, 'b', 2, 3, 'c', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If ascending order can't be guaranteed, then sorting is one possible solution for you.

```py
newObjects = ["b", "a", "c"]
newObjectIndices = [2, 0, 4]
existingList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for index, obj in reversed(sorted( zip(newObjectIndices, newObjects), key=lambda tup: tup[0])):
    existingList.insert(index, obj)

print(existingList)     # ['a', 0, 1, 'b', 2, 3, 'c', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```